# Compilation using 32-bit compiler gives different result from compilation using 64-bit compiler

Tags: c

Very simple program for test of speed gives different results if compiled with 32-bit compiler (Virtual Pascal 2.1, Free Pasacal 3.2.2, Delphi 3, Delphi 7, GCC 3.4.2, GFortran 3.4.2) or 64-bit compiler (Free Pascal 3.2.0, GCC 9.2.0, GFortran 9.2.0).
Code of the program is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

double y,yy[1000000];
int    i,j;

int main()
{
 y=1.0; i=1;

// for (i=1; i<=100; i++)
  for (j=1; j<=1000000; j++)
   {y=y-1.0/(i+j*y);
    yy[j]=y;}

 for (j=1; j<=200; j++) printf("%7d %25.15f\n",j,yy[j]);

 j=j+20;
 printf("%7d %25.15f\n",j,yy[1000000]);

 return 0;
}
```

If compiled with a 32-bit compiler, the last two rows of output are

```
        200         1.105809961129190
        221         1.283238771529100
```

If compiled with a 64-bit compiler, the last two rows of output are

```
        200         2.529262035756635
        221         9.276179925149263
```

No optimization was applied during compilation. Which result is correct?

Comment: Arrays in C start with index `0` up to `length-1`. All of your array accesses are off-by-one, including out of bounds access.

Comment: Both results were calculated by your own programs executed on your own machine. No tricks, no cheating, right? So both are 'correct' ...give or take accumulated rounding errors multiplied by one million.

Comment: Please format your code properly. Maybe there: https://codebeautify.org/c-formatter-beautifier

Answer (score 3):

Your program attempts to access `yy[1000000]` in the `for` loop (when `j` is 1000000) and in the `printf`. The array has 1,000,000 elements, so the index of the last element is only 999,999, not 1,000,000. Accessing beyond `yy[999999]` is not defined by the C standard. This may corrupt memory or cause other effects resulting in the output you observed.

To fix it, either change the definition of `yy` to have 1,000,001 elements or change the code to use index 0 to 999,999 instead of 1 to 1,000,000.

Answer (score 0):

When I look at your code, I see two issues;

1. the out-of-bound access to array, That has been address by comment from @Eugene Sh and the answer by @Eric Postpischil. I believe it is not the source of what you are observing here.
2. The nature of the sequence of operations performed by the program. The sequence of operations there is very sensitive because of the substraction (addition will do the same) of small numbers. But that is only the indirect source of the problem. The real problem there is most probably that in 64 bits programs, there are more registers available for local variables and intermediate results, which makes it possible to accumulate with higher precision. When you use the 32 bits program, there is less registers available for variables and intermediate results, forcing intermediate results of accumulations to be stored back in memory (or cache) with lower precision.
   To better understand that, it is important to say that CPU almost always compute using larger registers than the precision of variables, the result is then truncated when storing the result back to memory.

If you could accumulate starting from the last value of y (which does not seem easy looking at your model) you will see less difference. Similarly, if you do fewer iterations, you will see less differences.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the disassembly.  With `gcc -m32`, I see, in part:

```
    11ef:   db 45 f4                fildl  -0xc(%ebp)
    11f2:   dd 83 40 00 00 00       fldl   0x40(%ebx)
    11f8:   de c9                   fmulp  %st,%st(1)
    11fa:   de c1                   faddp  %st,%st(1)
    11fc:   d9 e8                   fld1   
    11fe:   de f1                   fdivp  %st,%st(1)
    1200:   de e9                   fsubrp %st,%st(1)
    1202:   dd 9b 40 00 00 00       fstpl  0x40(%ebx)
```

This is using the x87 FPU to compute the result.  These registers default to 80-bit floating-point numbers with 64 bits of precision.

Compare that with `gcc` (without the `-m32` option):

```
    118b:   f2 0f 59 cb             mulsd  %xmm3,%xmm1
    118f:   f2 0f 58 d1             addsd  %xmm1,%xmm2
    1193:   f2 0f 10 0d 7d 0e 00    movsd  0xe7d(%rip),%xmm1        # 2018 <_IO_stdin_used+0x18>
    119a:   00 
    119b:   f2 0f 5e ca             divsd  %xmm2,%xmm1
    119f:   f2 0f 5c c1             subsd  %xmm1,%xmm0
    11a3:   f2 0f 11 05 b5 2e 00    movsd  %xmm0,0x2eb5(%rip)        # 4060 <y>
    11aa:   00 
    11ab:   8b 05 d3 40 7a 00       mov    0x7a40d3(%rip),%eax        # 7a5284 <j>
    11b1:   f2 0f 10 05 a7 2e 00    movsd  0x2ea7(%rip),%xmm0        # 4060 <y>
```

Here the SSE2 registers are being used.  These are 64-bit floating-point numbers with 53 bits of precision.

I didn't analyze this fully, but this would explain the difference.

The other comments about the last printed result is still true.

To see what the right answer would be, I used the following maxima program:

```
fpprec: 200; /* 200 digits of precision */
y: 1b0; /* bigfloat number */
for j:1 to 200 do (y: y - 1/(1+j*y), printf(true, "~d: ~m~%", j, y));
```

The last couple of values are:

```
1: 5.0b-1
2: 0.0b0
3: - 1.0b0
4: - 6.6666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666667b-1
5: - 2.3809523809523809523809523809523809523809523809523809523809523809523809523809523809523809523809523809523809523809523809523809523809523809523809523809523809523809523809523809523809523809523809523809524b-1
...
199: 2.9134730438104486835684450669343781994684160775783702527498016474078580803950756073065445760100932978294411495273196565514143473753599906758526639607462515211042188884927808719790375365190366781832406b0
200: 2.9117598191464059260125139410787531875196505670673442081756913620541464298655107172850569895426676723484404517299155462989843760200675720715542525681413183321106093832508069466366241521724422505183095b0
```

Maxima could compute the exact values as rationals, but the fractions very quickly have a huge number of digits, so it slows down very much that I didn't want to wait.  Hence, bigfloats with 200 digits.  Larger number of digits could be easily done; I just hoped 200 digits would be enough.